# SQL Select Count and AVG

Tags: mysql, sql, select, count, average

Hi there!

I have some troubles with my SQL task, maybe somebody could help me with this.

We have 2 tables: Orders and Suppliers. It is needed to prepare a table with Supplier Name, Shipped Items and % of total orders.

I prepared almost the whole task but there is problem occured with filtering 2 of 3 suppliers that have orders quantity above average value.

> Here is Task description: select shippers that shipped an above average
>   (to column "Sender"), amount of orders they shipped (to column "Items
>   Sent") and percentage of shipping from overall amount (to column
>   "Quota", values have to be with '%' sign)

So here is my query:

```
SELECT Shippers.ShipperName AS 'Sender', COUNT(*) AS 'Item_Sent',
COUNT(*)/(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Orders) * 100 AS "Quota"
FROM Orders
JOIN Shippers ON Shippers.ShipperID=Orders.ShipperID
GROUP BY ShipperName
HAVING Item_Sent > (SELECT AVG(Item_Sent) from Orders);
```

Problem occurs with HAVING... - it does not selects 2 of 3 Suppliers with orders amount above average.

Comment: update your question add  a proper data sample and the expetced  result please

Comment: Yes, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 2):

You should not use quotes for column aliases but eventually backtics:

```
  SELECT Shippers.ShipperName AS `Sender`, COUNT(*) AS `Item_Sent`,
  COUNT(*)/(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Orders) * 100 AS "Quota"
  FROM Orders
  JOIN Shippers ON Shippers.ShipperID=Orders.ShipperID
  GROUP BY ShipperName
  HAVING Item_Sent > (SELECT AVG(Item_Sent) from Orders);
```

You can also try to not use aliases

```
  SELECT Shippers.ShipperName, COUNT(*),
  COUNT(*)/(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Orders) * 100
  FROM Orders
  JOIN Shippers ON Shippers.ShipperID=Orders.ShipperID
  GROUP BY ShipperName
  HAVING COUNT(*) > (SELECT AVG(Item_Sent) from Orders);
```